# Multiple Check Box Validation - Won't Recognize

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, checkbox

I have a form with quite a few questions where some are required and some aren't, which isn't an issue.

Below is a code where when the 'user' hits "Submit" and none of the '~12' check boxes are 'checked' it'll 'Alert' the user that 'One must be chosen'. However when 1 or more ARE checked it still shows the same 'Alert' stating that a check box needs to be chosen.

Validation method:

```
function validateForm()
{
    ////Multiple Check Box validation/////////////////

    var chks = document.getElementsByName("HealthConditions");
    var checkCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++)
    {
        if (chks[i].checked)
        {
            checkCount++;
        }
    }
    if (checkCount < 1)
    {
        alert("Please select at least one current health condition.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Body:

```
<form id="inshealthform" name="inshealthform" method="post" action="inshealthform_process.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

    <input id="HealthConditions"type="checkbox" name="HealthNoConditions" value="No Conditions" tabindex= "22"/>
          No conditions</td>
        <td width="38%" sizcache="3" sizset="11">
    <input id="HealthConditions" type="checkbox" name="HealthAlcohol" value="Alcohol/Substance Abuse" tabindex= "23"/>
        Alcohol/Substance Abuse</td>
        <td width="32%" sizcache="3" sizset="12">
    <input id="HealthConditions" type="checkbox" name="HealthAlzheimers" value="Alzheimer's Disease" tabindex= "24"/>
          Alzheimer's Disease</td>
      </tr>
```

blah blah blah.

"Submit Button"

Comment: Just a side point, remember to do some authentication client side (not just js) as js can be turned off.

Comment: Always add tags for the primary language(s) or your question will not have visibility subject matter experts. Also, your HTML is hard to follow. It looks like this is the beginning of a form plus an excerpt from a table within the form, but you haven't indicated that (I presume...or at least hope) there are missing lines between the <form> tag and the remainder, and your indentation is kind of scrambled.

Answer (score 1):

Your DOM query is looking for an attribute which - apparently - doesn't exist (`HealthConditions`).

Try something like this:

```
function validateForm() {

    var chks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
    var checkCount = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
        console.log(chks[i].checked)
        if (chks[i].checked) {
            checkCount++;
        }
    }

    if (checkCount < 1) {
        alert("Please select at least one current health condition.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5k84U/)

Also, HTML element IDs MUST be unique.